# Is it possible to sort through all emails in Outlook inbox from a specific sender using python?

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32

I need to sort through my corporate outlook account and want to sort through all of my emails that were sent by a certain address and locate all replies to that email.  My understanding is that I can use the win32com.client module to access my outlook and am able to read all of the "unread" emails in the folder.  However, I want to change the filter to read emails according to the specific sender. I can't seem to find a comprehensive list of methods than can be called on my messages object.  Can you specify a sender?

Here is my code so far:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]",True)

sender = 'xxxxx@xxxx.com'
for message in messages:
    if sender in message:
        print (message.body)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over all items in a folder is not really a good idea. Instead, you need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class in Outlook. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, you can use the following search criteria:

```
outItems = Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = " & "'" & address & "'")
```

Also, you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch  method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the Folder class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.